# Invalid Mac App Store Validation using iCloud Entitlements

Tags: macos, icloud, mac-app-store

I've been trying to simply validate an app for the Mac App Store. I was able to submit the iOS version without a hitch.

At this point in time i've configure the App ID in the dev portal to a unique iCloud identifier, so that eliminates the possibility that this is a shared ICID problem (iCloud ID).

I've recreated certificates, App ID, iCloud container, and distribution provisioning profiles.

*After days of troubleshooting, i've narrowed the issue down. If I assign the iCloud container to the App ID, validation fails. If I un-assign it, validation passes.

I have opened several tickets with Apple over the course of the week, but I haven't had a response so i'm hoping SO can help.

The errors reported by the validation tool:
[image]

My App ID: com.proj-build.cocoa-notes
My iCloud Container ID: iCloud.com.proj-build.cocoa-notes

- The prefixed iCloud in the iCloud Container ID confuses me. My iOS app does not specify the prefix in the entitlements file (using a different container ID) and it was validated. Prefix or no prefix on Mac does not work.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

### Entitlements configuration below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)com.proj-build.cocoa-notes</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier</key>
    <string>$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.app-scope</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.print</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your app ID and provisioning profile are misconfigured. The iCloud containers (those that match `iCloud.*`) are a Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite feature. You'll need to log in to the developer center and remove that, but keep the 10.9 (and previous) iCloud entitlement. Then regenerate the provisioning profile and use the new one.

Comment: There only appears to be one way to assign an iCloud container, and that enforces the iCloud prefix. I noticed when Yosemite was announced the iCloud prefix appeared (also forcing me to regenerate my developer provisioning profile at the time, i think... i remember some trouble generating dev profiles). I see no way to generate a 10.9 iCloud container. Also, validation worked perfectly using the iCloud.* with iOS7. Which seems contradictory. I also thought it was funny enabling iCloud appears as iCloud (Beta) in the dev portal.

Comment: I wrote the above because your situation sounds almost identical to one that came up at Apple's dev forums site. Maybe if you read through that you'll find something useful: https://devforums.apple.com/message/992625

Comment: So the process was, login to dev center. Navigate to your App ID, open the iCloud (Beta) view and uncheck any assigned iCloud Containers. Your App ID will show 'Configurable'. This is good. Regenerate provisioning profiles and rebuild. App is verified with iCloud entitlements enabled. Thanks Tom! Apple had also responded to my support ticket with similar instructions.